# How to present dictionary keys as buttons and get user input in flask?

Tags: python, flask, spotify

I have a flask script that currently grabs Spotify playlist information from the user. I want to present the names of the playlist to the user and have them pick a button that will return the playlist id to my script. So far I have:

```
playlist_api_endpoint = "{}/playlists".format(profile_data["href"])
playlists_response = requests.get(playlist_api_endpoint, 
headers=authorization_header)
playlist_data = json.loads(playlists_response.text)
```

Which will return a json much like:

```
    {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists",
  "items": [ {
    "collaborative": false,
    "external_urls": {
      "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c"
    },
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c",
    "id": "53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c",
    "images" : [ ],
    "name": "Wizzlers Big Playlist",
    "owner": {
      "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzler"
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler",
      "id": "wizzler",
      "type": "user",
      "uri": "spotify:user:wizzler"
    },
    "public": true,
    "snapshot_id" : "bNLWdmhh+HDsbHzhckXeDC0uyKyg4FjPI/KEsKjAE526usnz2LxwgyBoMShVL+z+",
    "tracks": {
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c/tracks",
      "total": 30
    }
```

I have the following code to grab the names and ids of all playlist:

```
 href_playlist_names = []
 href_playlist_id = []
 for items in playlist_data:
    href_playlist_names.append(items['items']['name'])
    href_playlist_id.append(items['items']['id'])
```

I want to know how build a rendered template that will present every name as a function and give back the corresponding id to my script as a python variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

1. Pass href_playlist_names into render template and create buttons.

Like This:

**app.py**

```
render_template("your_template_name.html", names = href_playlist_names)
```

**your_template_name.html**

```
{% for name in names %}
<button onclick = "give_id_to_server({{name}})" >{{name}}</button>
{% endfor %}

<script>
function give_id_to_server(name) {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:your_port/receive_id',
            data: name,
        });
}
</script>
```

Then in your app.py, make a flask routing point to receive the data like this:

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/receive_id')
def do_something_with_id():
    *do whatever you want to with the id
```

Hope this helps!